# check the printer status in the event of the ReportViewer

Tags: c#, printing, reportviewer, status

## I have a problem, hope everybody help please.

I write code print in event Print of reportViewer, but don't check status print.

Example: if printer is turn off, when click button print and choose printer then click OK. The print job is sent but still pending although exactly informed that the printer is turned off..

I do not know what to write code in the reportview events to be able to check the status of the printer before printing.

Hope everyone guide.
Here is the code

```
    private void rptInHoaDon_Print(object sender, Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportPrintEventArgs e)
    {
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\root\cimv2");
        scope.Connect();

        string printerName = "";
        // Choose Printers from WMI Object Collections
        string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer ");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

        //ManagementObjectCollection coll = searcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject printer in searcher.Get())
        {
            printerName = printer["Name"].ToString().ToLower();
            if (printerName.Equals(@"OOTOYA"))
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Printer = " + printer["Name"]+" - " + printer["WorkOffline"]);
                if (printer["WorkOffline"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("false"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        List<PrintSystemJobInfo> jobInfos = new List<PrintSystemJobInfo>();
                        LocalPrintServer server = new LocalPrintServer();
                        while (true)
                        {
                            foreach (var jobInfo in server.DefaultPrintQueue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection())
                            {
                                SpotTroubleUsingJobAttributes(jobInfo);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show( ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The printer is turned off");
                    //job.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

List item

Comment: Tks you,next time I will make a more accurate